# Why Do we need Isolated USB to TTL converter cable for communication between Desktop CPU and target?

Tags: embedded, meter

We can use non-isolated USB to TTL cable in between battery operated devices, But when we are dealing with AC devices like communication between Desktop CPU and Electric meter(Embedded MCU), we need isolated USB to TTL converter. Any one please help why we need that in this case?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. Please post your question on [StackExchange/Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @thebusybee FWIW, OP did post this question on [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/608207/56807) - however, it was closed there due to the perceived lack of clarity or detail.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about electronics and was cross-posted to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/608207/56807